# Positioning an absolute positioned form inside an absolute positioned div

Tags: html, css

I am trying to position an absolute positioned form inside an absolute positioned div

```
<div style="position: relative; background-color: white;width: 639px;height: 626px;">
  <div style="position: absolute;height: 442px; width: 639px; top: 184px; background-color: #F1F1F1">
    <form style="width: 100%;height:100px;position: absolute; margin: 42px 48px auto 48px; background-color: green" >
    </form>   
  </div>
</div>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/flamant/7u9kz6xc/10/

But the green form exceed from its parent instead of staying inside its parent. Why? If you could give me some detailed explanation, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The green block exceeds the parent width because it has a width of 100% and you have to add the margin width, which is 48px.

If you want to stop at the end of the parent, just change the width property to:

```
width: calc(100% - 48px);
```

If you want to have the same distance from the left and from the right, double it:

```
width: calc(100% - 96px);
```

Here's a working live codepen: https://codepen.io/alezuc/pen/RwWrpKV